Visual Studio 2022 launchsettings.json with RemoteDebugEnabled not working
In my visual studio 2022 c# Console application I try to debug on a remote machine.
My intension is to start the project direct out of visual studio. I know its also possible to start the executable on the remote machine and attach in visual studio. This is already working.
But in this case I want to start the project/executable direct from VS.
For this I edited the launchsettings.json file which was automaticaly generated.
But its not working as expected.
That's the content of my launchsettings.json file
{
  "profiles": {
    "local": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "nativeDebugging": true
    },
    "remote": {
      "commandName": "Executable",
      "executablePath": "C:\\Dev\\MyApplication.exe",
      "workingDirectory": "C:\\Dev\\",
      "remoteDebugEnabled": true,
      "remoteDebugMachine": "172.21.94.32:4026",
      "authenticationMode": "Windows",
      "nativeDebugging": true
    }
  }
}

I always get the error that the path of the executable can not be found.
For my understanding this path should be on the remote machine.
I tried a lots of things.
Set the executable to the path on remote
Set the executable to a local path
Set commandName "Project" and set only the working directory (remote and local)
but its not working. Always the path or executable can not be found.
as I already mentioned, attach to process is working. So the problem is not on the connection.
What's the correct way to configure this launchsettings.json file for remote debbuging?

Because in remote debugging you are to attach to a running process on remote machine with a remote debugging service running, not to launch it and then attach the debugger. When you're specifying command name: Executable and then specifying the executablePath you're telling the debugger that you want to start a new process on you local machine with specified executable. I'm not sure about actual properties names for remote debugging in launchSettings.json, you can look it up on MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-csharp?view=vs-2022

@ZecosMAX so you mean its not possible to start a process on the remote machine.
If I use the old project file format with the csproj.user you can define the Parameter StartProgram and if you also set the RemoteDebugEnabled to true. The Program is started on the remote machine.
